# android ant build fails to install apk but works via IDE?

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, crashlytics

I am trying to build a android app via jenkins and ant and the issue is that once it builds with no errors, the app fails to launch after install due to crashlytics.

The exact same app builds and runs perfectly fine using an IDE like Eclipse and all the necesary crashlyitics libs are located in the projects /lib folder.

here is the stack trace of the error when the app is launched.

```
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jr/com.jr.HomeActivity}: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here: 
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): https://crashlytics.com/register/4346dsd1c0dsadadq77cf/android/com.jr
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): Caused by: com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): This app relies on Crashlytics. Configure your build environment here: 
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119): https://crashlytics.com/register/fdsfdsfdsfdsfdssdfdsf/android/com.jr
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.crashlytics.android.j.a(SourceFile:52)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:913)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.start(SourceFile:212)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.start(SourceFile:190)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at com.jr.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:134)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-03 10:56:24.351: E/AndroidRuntime(8119):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Hi, Did you resolve this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

okay the lib they mention in the logcat:

https://crashlytics.com/register/4346dsd1c0dsadadq77cf/android/com.jr

its probably missing form the libs folder or Jenkins is not picking it up

Comment: How is jenkins missing it? The lib is inside the projects lib folder

Answer (score 1):

Hemal from Crashlytics here!

If you run through the [Ant setup](https://www.crashlytics.com/downloads/ant), you'll be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

Just had to run `./gradlew clean` before assembly.